# JavaScript Alert in a Vb.net Class

Tags: javascript, vb.net

i have this function :

```
Public Sub javaMsg(ByVal message As String)
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()

    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")

    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")

    sb.Append("alert('")

    sb.Append(message)

    sb.Append("')};")

    sb.Append("</script>")

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

i need to put it in a vb class so i can be able to use it in all my pages but i'm getting an error on "Page.ClientScript" saying that "Reference to a non-shred member requires an object reference"

How can i solve this please :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just change it to;

```
Public Function javaMsg(ByVal message As String) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()   
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")

    return sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

Then on your page call;

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", javaMsg("Hello World"), true)
```

*Notice that there is an overloaded RegisterClientScriptBlock which actually renders the script blocks for you.*

This way your function can be in what ever class you want and will not break.

Alternatively, you can pass the current page as a reference to your method;

```
Public Sub javaMsg(ByRef page As System.Web.UI.Page, ByVal message As String)

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()   
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")

    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString(), true)

End Sub
```

And on your page call;

```
'' C# does not allow you to pass the page as a Reference type. Not sure if VB.Net does or not
'' So creating a reference to it before passing it in
Dim refPage As System.Web.UI.Page = me.Page
ClassName.javaMsg(refPage, "Hello World")
```